# Leaping image just before Constraint animation

Tags: ios, animation, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm using Constraints within my app and have have a reasonable level of success so far; everything visual object in the gif below is Constrained.

The issue is that when selected, tiles leap to another location before animating to the final, correct destination.

From a code perspective, on a tile click, higher priority positioning Constraints are applied to the tile, the tile is added as a subview to the blue area, then animation is performed.

Can anyone shed a little light on what's happening here?

Thanks

[image: Leaping UIButtons before animation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the behavior I'm seeing in your gif, I would guess that when you move the tile views between superviews (the blue area vs. the larger white area), the view jumps to it's current frame position (within the coordinate system of the old superview), but now in the coordinate system of the new superview.

The solution, I think, would be to translate the final position in the new superview to a position in the current superview, perform the animation, and only when the animation completes would you move the view to it's new superview.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks a lot!